# When comparing PCA and FA Models, is it possible to have a model with lower explained variance, but a higher Log Likelihood?

Tags: pca, scikit-learn, factor-analysis

Having a model with a higher log-likelihood and lower explained variance doesn't make sense to me.  The Bing AI thing says it's impossible... I'm new to these analyses and the log-likelihood statistic.  The difference is so tiny (see below) I'm tempted to call it a rounding error, but I'd like to better understand what is going on if I can.  Is there something I'm missing or should know?

I'm running a five-fold cross-validation of a PCA and a Factor Analysis model.

```
data= pe_growth_earn[bad_PE_PEG_TY_Final_filter]
cross_val_dict = dict()

fa = FactorAnalysis(n_components=1)
pca = PCA(n_components = 1)

cross_val_dict['rel_letg_ty_pca'] = cross_val_score(pca, data[['Rel_LTEG', 'Rel_TY_Final']])
cross_val_dict['fa_rel_letg_ty'] = cross_val_score(fa, data[['Rel_LTEG', 'Rel_TY_Final']])


cross_val_dict_sorted = dict(sorted(cross_val_dict.items(), key=lambda item: np.mean(item[1]), reverse=True))
for k,v in cross_val_dict_sorted.items():
    print(k, np.mean(v), np.std(v))
```

You can see they have the same variables.  I get:

```
fa_rel_letg_ty -3.0702495295898276 1.0239627390665273
rel_letg_ty_pca -3.0723270850577697 1.02128110579763
```

fa_rel_letg_ty (the Factor Analysis model) has a slightly higher average log-likelihood (by about 2 thousandths); however, its explained variance (calculated elsewhere via `explained_variance_score(data[['Rel_LTEG', 'Rel_TY_Final']], np.dot(df, model.components_)`) is much worse (about 10% vs 50%).

I've done some simple sample testing and the explained variance difference is fairly constant.

Comment: The question could be improved by explaining in words what you try to do rather than only showing code. Not everybody works with the same software system, and it is generally not much fun to try to decipher somebody else's code.

Comment: Hi, @ChristianHennig, I've tried to explain the code more.  The more theoretical question of the difference in explained variance vs log-likelihood could possibly be answered without the code.